AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001335: Ambiguous dependencies for type PersistenceProvider with qualifiers
How do I fix this exception?  It is preventing me from starting a Helidon server.  I am running TestNG from Eclipse IDE.  This does not happen if I execute mvn clean package.
...
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001335: Ambiguous dependencies for type PersistenceProvider with qualifiers 
 Possible dependencies: 
  - Configurator Bean [class io.helidon.integrations.cdi.jpa.JpaExtension, types: PersistenceProvider, Object, DelegatePersistenceProvider, LogPersistenceProvider, qualifiers: @Any @Default],
  - Configurator Bean [class io.helidon.integrations.cdi.jpa.JpaExtension, types: PersistenceProvider, qualifiers: @Default @Any @Named]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.checkBeanResolved(InstanceImpl.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingWeldInstance.get(ForwardingWeldInstance.java:44)
    at io.helidon.integrations.cdi.jpa.EntityManagerFactories.getPersistenceProvider(EntityManagerFactories.java:222)
    at io.helidon.integrations.cdi.jpa.EntityManagerFactories.createContainerManagedEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactories.java:161)
    at io.helidon.integrations.cdi.jpa.JpaExtension.lambda$addContainerManagedEntityManagerFactoryBeans$1(JpaExtension.java:1033)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.configurator.BeanConfiguratorImpl$CreateCallback.create(BeanConfiguratorImpl.java:372)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.configurator.BeanConfiguratorImpl$CreateCallback.access$700(BeanConfiguratorImpl.java:339)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.configurator.BeanConfiguratorImpl$ImmutableBean.create(BeanConfiguratorImpl.java:511)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at io.helidon.integrations.cdi.jpa.EntityManagerFactory$_$$_WeldClientProxy.isOpen(Unknown Source)
    at io.helidon.integrations.cdi.jpa.JpaExtension.onStartup(JpaExtension.java:2053)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$DefaultMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
    at jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:96)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.doStart(HelidonContainerImpl.java:340)
    at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:137)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.start(HelidonContainerImpl.java:250)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:76)


The main Eclipse project has a dependent project that is also in Eclipse.  The dependent project generates /target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml.
When the dependent project is built with mvn, the maven-jar-plugin is configured to exclude META-INF/persistence.xml.  So, Maven builds work.
When the main project runs in Eclipse, Eclipse includes the dependent project's persistence.xml.  The main project also has a persistence.xml.  This makes 2 persistence.xml accessible to Weld.  Weld then does not know how to deal with 2 PersistenceProviders.
The solution is to delete the persistence.xml from the dependent project.  The main project unit test code does so before starting the Helidon server.
